# Android: how to find the directory of a file

Tags: android, shell

Once you access the shell (or also through adb is fine) of an android phone you can use

```
ls -R | grep "filename"
```

to search for a file and if the file is there the shell reports happily that it is there. But how do you actually see which directory the file is in? Is there a command that I could add so that the directory of the file is listed along with its name? My phone is rooted and I can ofcourse use file explorer applications but I want to do it through shell.

Thanks

Comment: what is pwd how is it used?

Comment: I did pwd enter and then entered the same search command and nothing changed, if that is what you propsed. What is pwd supposed to do?

Comment: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pwd.htm

Comment: When I use find and the file is found I am now in the directory of the file so pwd does not help